# Roku: BrightScript: How to set custom font and color for Label?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am trying to set a custom font for the label but it's not working, not sure whats the proper way to do it.

CreateLabel.brs

```
    font = CreateObject("roSGNode", "Font")
    font.uri = "pkg:/fonts/GothamMedium.ttf"
    font.size = "24"

    m.top.setFocus(true)
    m.label1 = m.top.findNode("label1")
    m.label1.font.size = 20
    m.label1.text = "Hello"
    ' m.label1.font = font -> if uncommented, then text doesn't show up
    m.label1.color="0x72D7EEFF"

end function
```

m.label1.font = font // is not working

CreataLabel.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<component name="CreateLabel" extends="Scene">

    <interface>
        <field id="label1" type="string" />
    </interface>

    <script type="text/brightscript" uri="pkg:/components/CreateLabel/CreateLabel.brs" />
    <script type="text/brightscript" uri="pkg:/source/Main.brs" />

    <children>

        <Label
            id="label1"
            text="Narendra"
            width="200"
            height="100"
            horizAlign="center"
            vertAlign="center"
        />    
    </children>

</component>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this-

Instead of

```
font.size = "24"
```

try

```
font.size = 24
```

i.e. font size should be integer.
Comment below line-

```
'm.label1.font.size = 20
```

Un-comment this line-

```
m.label1.font = font
```

It should work. Color setting looks fine.

Alternatively, If you want to set the font in xml, you can try something like this-

```
<Label
        id="label1"
        text="Narendra"
        width="200"
        height="100"
        horizAlign="center"
        vertAlign="center" >
        <Font role = "font" uri = "pkg:/fonts/GothamMedium.ttf" size = "24" />
</Label>
```

Note that every property's(field/attribute) value will be in double quotes in xml file(even integers) but this is not the case with brs files. Also make sure that font file(GothamMedium.ttf) is available at the mentioned path(pkg:/fonts/GothamMedium.ttf).

Comment: thank you @Swaran  but none of this helped.

```
Function init()

    font = CreateObject("roSGNode", "Font")
    font.uri = "pkg:/fonts/GothamMedium.ttf"
    font.size = 24
    
    m.top.setFocus(true)
    m.label1 = m.top.findNode("label1")
    m.label1.font = font
    m.label1.color="0x72D7EEFF"
end function
```

Comment: @Naren, It seems you are missing something in your code. Please try to figure out what you are missing by comparing with this code- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZxMCUr5Fqtv2zqSBIogSTG5fHV9HX1OM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you @Swaran but still it doesn't show. I also checked Roku's version and seeing that I have latest update.

Comment: @Naren, Did you try to side load the zip file I shared in above comment. Please share your project like I shared with you in zip file.

Comment: thank you for help .. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1y3wWwzwQGMP4YYdX4MHVpROsMF5WUKMx?usp=sharing

Comment: @Naren, Although there are some small mistakes but code is working fine. As I observed when unzipping the file, I think you are doing some mistake in zipping the file. You have to zip different components in the zip file not the parent folder. For example in your uploaded file, unzip the file and side-load hello-world.zip file on the device. It will work as expected.

Comment: @Naren, This is your file, you can download it side-load on the device as it is. It should work-https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h4FnZckWpbQ_gi55jX2KK8AyEqrd7F5R/view?usp=sharing